# Effective way to case match a tuples with boolean values in scala

Tags: scala

I want to case match tuples which contain boolean values.
Is there an effective way to match  the results as case match on boolean looksexhautive

```
val ABC= "abc"
val DEF = "def"

private def istest1 = true
private def istest2 = true
private def istest3 = true

(istest1, istest2, istest3) match {

  case (true, true, true)=>ABC
  case (false, true, true) =>DEF
  case (false , false , true)=> //print something else

  //other cases
}
```

Comment: Your approach seems pretty much okay. What specific problem do you have with it?

Comment: Looks too exhaustive case match

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have a statement for each of the possible outcomes, and using `match` seems to be the most compact and readable way to do it.

One possible improvement is to use `_` for "don't care" values:

```
(istest1, istest2, istest3) match {
  case (true, true, true) => ABC
  case (_, true, true) => DEF
  case (false, _, true) => //print something 
  case _ =>  //other cases
}
```

There may be performance issues with different versions of these tests, but it is best to pick the one that makes the most sense. Aim for readability and maintainability above perceived performance.

Comment: I would remove the `_` from the second case. It's confusing, it will actually always match on `false`.

Comment: any possible way we can we ignore the case match as there might be case like (false, false , true) and every permutation needs an different action

Comment: @coder25 what exactly you mean with "ignore the case match" ? - "every permutation needs an different action", you can write a case statement for each permutation and do what you need to do for every case, what exactly is wrong with that?

Comment: By ignoring i mean any alternative to case match

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems fine, but given all of your values are boolean you could use some stable identifiers to name them and make the code a bit more readable

```
val ABC = "abc"
val DEF = "def"

def isTest1 = true
def isTest2 = true
def isTest3 = true

val PassedTest1 = true
val PassedTest2 = true
val PassedTest3 = true

val NotPassedTest1 = false
val NotPassedTest2 = false

(isTest1, isTest2, isTest3) match {

    case (PassedTest1, PassedTest2, PassedTest3)       => ABC
    case (NotPassedTest1, _, PassedTest3)    => DEF
    case (NotPassedTest1, NotPassedTest2, PassedTest3) => //print something
    case _                                             => ???
  }
```

Also as @Tim mentioned, you can use `_` to match any value inside the tuple, or to match any tuple as the last case so you don't have to be exaustive

Answer (score 0):

I would even go one step further to Brunos solution:

```
sealed trait PassedOrNot {
  final val Passed    = true
  final val NotPassed = false
}

case object Test1 extends PassedOrNot
case object Test2 extends PassedOrNot
case object Test3 extends PassedOrNot

def isTest1 = true
def isTest2 = true
def isTest3 = true

(isTest1, isTest2, isTest3) match {
  // @formatter:off
  case (Test1.Passed   , Test2.Passed, Test3.NotPassed) => ???
  case (Test1.NotPassed, _           , Test3.NotPassed) => ???
  case _                                                => ???
  // @formatter:on
}
```